# Какие "nuget-файлы" нужно сохранять в репозитории

Tags: c#

Имеется C# проект. Устанавливаю стороннюю библиотеку через пакетный менеджер `nuget`. После установки пакета создаются файлы

- `packages.config` в самом проекте
- различные файлы в папке `packages`. В нем лежат нужные файлы библиотек, плюсом файл с расширением `.nupkg`.

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие файлы достаточно залить в репозиторий системы контроля версий, а какие можно проигнорировать? Как предполагаю, установленные файлы библиотек `nuget` на другой машине разработчика автоматически сам должен выкачать, их заливать необязательно?

Comment: Нужен только `packages.config`

Comment: @Monk, понял. Напишите в виде ответа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию, не трогая настроек, достаточно хранить только *packages.config*. Более подробно об этом, а также о том, какие файлы можно и нужно добавить в ignore, можно почитать в [официальной документации](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore).